# Pandas: Updating a rolling average only every minute for one second data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where rows of data are in one second intervals, so 08:00:00, 08:00:01, etc. I want to take a rolling average over a period of 10 minutes, but I only want the rolling average to update on a minute by minute basis. So the rolling average values for 08:10:00 - 08:10:59 would all be the same value, and then at 8:11:00, it would update to a new value for the next minute.

Currently I'm using the following line to calculate a rolling average which updates every second:

```
df['counts-avg'] = df['counts'].rolling(window=600).mean()
```

Comment: what is going wrong

Comment: Nothing is going wrong. I'm just not sure how to do what I want to do. This command has a rolling average that changes with every second. I want it to only do the rolling average update every 60 seconds.

Comment: df.groupby(df.index // 600).first()? Or something of the sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have another column for the seconds value called df['sec']. I got the indices of rows where seconds = 0 (the zeroth second of each minute) and replaced every other row with np.nan. Then I used fillna(method='ffill') to copy values downward.

```
df['counts-avg'] = df['counts'].rolling(window=600).mean()
erase_idx = df[df['sec'] > 0].index.values
ma = df['counts-avg']
ma.loc[erase_idx] = np.nan
ma = ma.fillna(method='ffill')
```